# Standard fields in all Django models classes

Tags: django, design-patterns, django-models

What is the optimal way to implement standard fields that I would like all classes in Django models to have?

### Option 1

Option 1 is to create the standard fields in a parent class and then have every class inherit that class. For instance:

[image: option 1]

### Option 2

Option 2 is to create a class with the standard fields that has a composite relationship to the other classes. For instance:

[image: option 2]

### Option 3

Option 3 is simply to duplicate these fields in each of the classes that wishes to use them (which violates the DRY principle of Django). For example:

[image: option 3]

Which is optimal for a notes field and created and last modified datetimes (and in the future also user id)? I clearly will wish to use these fields for auditing purposes, which means they will be displayed in Django Admin in some way. Keep this in mind when helping me determine which approach is optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question suggests that you want to build an abstract class to use as a base class for your models to inherit from.  There is some really great documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

For example:

```
class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    last_modified_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True # This line is what makes the class an abstract class

    def we_all_do_this(self):
        pass

    def we_all_do_this_too(self):
        pass

class ChildA(CommonInfo):   # Note that ChildA class inherits from the CommonInfo abstract base class 
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)

    def only_i_do_this(self):
        pass


class ChildB(CommonInfo):   # Note that ChildB class inherits from the CommonInfo abstract base class
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)

    def only_i_do_this(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks! This is kind of what I thought (generalization/inheritance), but I wasn't aware that Django had specific abstract class design in mind already! Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome.  The magic is in that class Meta block of code.  There are some really cool things you can do inside that block beyond inheritance: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a right answer to this question but if it is compulsory fields I expect to implement across all models in a project, I would go with the parent class approach.

i.e., your option 1.